# Data Limitation on send and receive using Binary Formatter (Socket Programming, TCP Client) .net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, socket.io

I am doing some work Related to socket programming in C# .net. So if you want to send List of Object through socket (obviously in bytes) then the receiver do not have information about the length of List and how many bytes should it read, unless you send information about the length before sending the List (simple and obvious solution). **But what if I use Binary Formatter, I don't have to worry about the size Right??** and can I send as many data as I want by using this approach, **is there any Limit?** Limit to send and receive data through this.

This is Part for Sending Data

```
                 TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(serverip, serverport);
               NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(ns, List<Object>);
```

This is for Receiving Data..

```
               List<Object> list=(List<Object>)formatter.Deserialize(ns);
```

**FYI:**  I have tested it for like 2+ millions objects, its working fine. **Should I continue using this?**

Answer (score 0):

As you use NetworkStream the techical limitation on the size is long.MaxValue.
But you should consider several things:

- The bigger the size of data your send the higher probability of network errors and therefor probability of failure to get your data. Consider sending data in some chunks, so if one chunk is failed you can easily resend it. In short sending 1Mb in this way is Ok, sending 1Gb is a problem.
- The BinaryFormatter serialization has some big other head and increase of transferred size significantly. In some case (depending on you actual classes and data) it might be even more than sending JSON over http.
- Choosing Sockets as a transport has sense if you need the maximum control of what you are doing and to do some deep optimization. In simpler cases consider using WCF or WebAPI.

Comment: My requirement is to communicate using LAN  and a very controlled communication so WebAPI is out of question. and Lets say I am sending 1 GB and if 1 packet is lost or corrupted, isn't TCP protocol takes care of it?

Comment: @Ateeq, TCP takes some efforts on low level to handle some network troubles but when it finally fails your should handle it by itself on your app level. In your case it means that you failed to send or receive your entire packet.

Comment: @Ateeq, what kind of control do you need over your communication that leads to using Sockets?

Comment: Ok I guess this posted method will do fine with my requirement. I do not have to send 1 GB data right now. I was just wondering if in future when data increases (a very little possibility) then I don't need to change the logic.
I need Specific Amount of data to be transferred in real real time. there should not be a tiny delay and my requirement is to use LAN.